# how do i Combining the AND condition in same query

Tags: postgresql

i want to use more then one and condition in same query

kind of this:

```
SELECT fieldvalue 
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(fielddata) AS fieldvalue,
         process_id as process_id 
  FROM field
) t 
WHERE t.process_id='8fea394a83b70569432382e1dadc629b'
  AND (t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '211115ghfghfhfhff' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NULL)
```

in query FIELD is view and in view FIELDVALUE in column name with jsonb type and problem is running where condition individually gives result

```
SELECT fieldvalue 
    FROM (
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements(fielddata) AS fieldvalue,
             process_id as process_id 
      FROM field
    ) t 
    WHERE t.process_id='8fea394a83b70569432382e1dadc629b'
      AND (t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NOT NULL)
```

but when running with two AND its gives 0 rows

```
SELECT fieldvalue 
    FROM (
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements(fielddata) AS fieldvalue,
             process_id as process_id 
      FROM field
    ) t 
    WHERE t.process_id='8fea394a83b70569432382e1dadc629b'
      AND (t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NOT NULL) 
      AND (t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '211115ghfghfhfhff' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NULL) AND ....;
```

Comment: That's valid syntax. What exactly is your question? Also: you don't select from "fields" you select from tables

Comment: actually  this query runs on VIEW in which part of jsonb field is store of table FIELD is view and in view FIELDVALUE in column name with jsonb type  and problem is running where condition individually gives result but when running with two AND its gives 0 rows

Comment: Do you mean to combine those with an `OR` maybe? something like `where (x = 1 and y = 2) or (x = 5 and y = 6)`

Comment: no i want to AND not OR where (x = 1 and y = 2) and (x = 5 and y = 6)

Comment: data in table is store like [{"x":"1","y":{"z":"2"},{"x":"5","y":{"z":"6"}]

Comment: `(x = 1 and y = 2) and (x = 5 and y = 6) ` can **never** be true. x can't have the value `1` **and** the value `5` at the same time.

Comment: i know but there is any other way to do that thing?

Comment: Define "that thing" please. You understood that x can't be equal to 1 and 5 at the same time, you insist on combining with AND and not OR, what's the issue about getting 0 rows then ? There are no row with x=1 AND x=5. If you want the result of the x=1 AND also the result of x=5 then you need to put a OR as already suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying data on the basis of

> **t.fieldvalue->'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf'** and **t.fieldvalue->'name' = '211115ghfghfhfhff'**

Expression is evaluating to false and it is not returning anything. Its just like asking for a fruit which is banana and also a mango.
If you want to query the field which will return both the values corresponding to

> **t.fieldvalue->'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf'** and **t.fieldvalue->'name' = '211115ghfghfhfhff'**

then consider using **"OR"**.

So you might want to query this :

```
SELECT fieldvalue  FROM (  
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(fielddata) AS fieldvalue,
         process_id as process_id    FROM field ) t  
WHERE t.process_id='8fea394a83b70569432382e1dadc629b'   
AND (  
(t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '21312ghfhgfhfghgf' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NOT NULL)  
OR  
(t.fieldvalue->>'name' = '211115ghfghfhfhff' AND t.fieldvalue->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NULL)  
)
```

Comment: maybe we can use function or if condition